# Hypergeometric series of sine function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Can someone please help me express this integral in terms of hypergeometric series?

$$\int\frac{\sin⁡((2n-1)x)}{\sin⁡x}\text dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle\frac{i e^{-2 i n x} \left(n e^{2 i x} \, _2F_1\left(1,1-n;2-n;e^{2ix}\right)+(n-1) e^{4 i n x} \, _2F_1\left(1,n;n+1;e^{2 i x}\right)\right)}{2(n-1) n}$$

Comment: Could you share how you made this step?

Comment: Yes, I used Mathematica. The OP wanted the answer only...

Comment: @IgorRivin OP did not specify that they were not looking for proof, and usually people on math.SE like proof, so if you got your answer by Mathematica, put that you got it from Mathematica in your answer (also having words in an answer is usually nice).